# Sort a hashmap and get a key in an order (2nd key, 3rd, etc.)

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, Integer>` list and I want to sort it by integers and be able to get a key in a certain order (for example: get the 3rd, or 5th key).
How do I go by doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have a HashMap<String, Integer> list"? Do you mean `List<HashMap<String,Integer>>` or something else? Also what do you want to get as result when you "get the 3rd"?

Comment: Basically, I'm working on a scoreboard, and I want the player to see their placement, so basically where they are positioned, using the values.

Comment: How about instead of using map using `List<ScoreInfo>` where ScoreInfo will be class holding `String name; Integer score`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't sort a `HashMap`. The order of entries within a `HashMap` is kinda random.

You could use `myMap.keySet()` to extract the keys (in random order) and put them in a new ordered collection (= `List` or `SortedSet`), for example: `new ArrayList<>(myMap.keySet());`. And then sort this `List`.

Or you use a `SortedMap` with a custom `Comparator` instead of a `HashMap`.